# Can i get msi parameters as it is

Tags: windows-installer

My product have 2 MSI's. One is for x86 (x86.msi) and another is x64 (x64.msi).

I want to club them in single msi (dummy.msi). Depending on platform, i want to invoke appropriate MSI. I created a custom UI action to do this.

Is there a way to get all parameters passed to MSI? i will use same parameters lo lanch x86/x64 MSI.

Ex: dummy.msi /qn param1=val1 param2=val2
how can i get  **/qn param1=val1 param2=val2**  later i will pass to

x86.msi  /qn param1=val1 param2=val2
or
x64.msi  /qn param1=val1 param2=val2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI does not support nesting or chaining like that natively. What you are looking for is a bootstrapper/chainer.